# Passing Java exception to JenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am invoking a Java class as part of my Jenkins pipleine. I want to pass or fail the pipeline based on the exception retureeened from the main class. I am trying something like this.

```
script{
  try{
    sh ' mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com..test.Deployer" -Dexec.args="qal"'
  }catch (Exception e) {
    echo 'exception::' + e.toString()
    echo 'message::' + e.getMessage()
    echo 'cause::' + e.getCause()
    if (e.toString().contains("NoChangeDetectedException")) {
      currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      return    
    }
  }
}
```

But from the Jenkins log, I see the original exception is not getting passed.

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: 
exception:: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
message:: script returned exit code 1
cause:: null
```

Is it possible to get the actual message in the Jenkins file?
Note: `getStackTrace` is not permitted for our pipeline.

Comment: The reason your Java exception is not accessible is because you are invoking a shell step method which executes a shell interpreter. If you executed the Java class directly from within Groovy, then you could catch the Java exception. As it is currently, you would need to parse and handle the shell interpreter exception. Your choice as to which of the two you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception(InvocationTargetException) you caught is not threw by java class(com..test.Deployer), it is threw by `sh` step, so there is no message or stackTrace about your class `com..test.Deployer`.

Meanwhile, `sh` step doesn't provide a good way to capture stderr, and the `returnStdout` parameter of `sh` doesn't work when script exit with error.

There is a workground to get the mvn output, by write mvn output to a temp file, using `-DoutputFile`

```
script {
    stderrfile = 'stderr.out' //temp file
    shout = '' //doesn't work for this question
    try{
        shout = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass='com..test.Deployer' -Dexec.args='qal' -DoutputFile=${stderrfile}")
        echo 'shout::' + shout
    }catch (Exception e) {
        errmsg = readFile(stderrfile)
        echo 'errmsg::' + errmsg
        echo 'shout::' + shout
        echo 'exception::' + e.toString()
        echo 'message::' + e.getMessage()
        echo 'cause::' + e.getCause()
        if (e.toString().contains("NoChangeDetectedException")) {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
            return    
        }
    }
}
```

The error message will be in the `errmsg = readFile(stderrfile)`.